# Preserving binary products implies it preserves non-zero finite products?

Tags: category-theory

*Definition*: A functor $F \colon C \to D$ preserves $n$-products if for every $n$-product $\prod_{i=1}^n A_i$ in $C$, the canonical map $\langle F\pi_1 , \dots F\pi_n \rangle \colon F(\prod_{i=1}^n A_i) \to \prod_{i=1}^n F(A_i)$ is an isomorphism.

*Question*: If a functor preserves binary products, does it also preserves $n$-products, for $n>2$? Sounds very plausible but I haven’t been able to prove this. What if we assume $C$ has all $n$-products?

Comment: Ok. If $C$ has all $n$-products, can't you prove that they are (canonically isomorphic to) towers of binary products?

Comment: @AnneBauval indeed I have proved that but preserving $n$-products requires the canonical map to be an isomorphism, but I haven't been able to show this one factors as a composition of isomorphisms between binary products

Comment: Try for $n=3$ ?

Comment: I have, and failed. To be clear, I need to decompose $\langle F\pi_1, F\pi_2, F\pi_3 \rangle$ into a composition of pairs $\langle F\pi_x, F\pi_y_3 \rangle$, I haven't been able to do this

Comment: Before applying $F$ (or even if there is no $F$), exhibit a canonical isomorphism between $\prod_{i=1}^3A_i$ and $\prod_{j=1}^2B_j$ where for instance $B_1= \prod_{i=1}^2A_i$ and $B_2=A_3.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Background

Products can be constructed recursively as follows:

1. Let $Q$ be a product of $A_1, \dotsc, A_{n - 1}$ with canonical projections $q_j \colon Q \to A_j$.
   Let $P$ be product of $Q$ and $A_n$ with canonical projections $π \colon P \to Q$ and $p_n \colon P \to A_n$.
   Let $p_j ≔ q_j ∘ π$ for every $j = 1, \dotsc, n - 1$.
   Then the object $P$ together with the morphisms $p_1, \dotsc, p_n$ is a product for $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$.

We also have a partial converse:

2. Let $P$ be a product of $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ with canonical projections $p_i \colon P \to A_i$.
   Let $Q$ be a product of $A_1, \dotsc, A_{n - 1}$ with canonical projections $q_j \colon Q \to A_j$.
   Then there exists a unique morphism $π$ from $P$ to $Q$ with $q_j ∘ π = p_j$ for every $j = 1, \dotsc, n - 1$.
   The object $P$ together with the two morphisms $π \colon P \to Q$ and $p_n \colon P \to A_n$ is a product of the two objects $Q$ and $A_n$.

[image: The various morphisms arranged in a diagram.]

#### The problem at hand

Let us assume that the category $\mathcal{C}$ has binary products.
It then follows by induction that $\mathcal{C}$ has $n$-products for every $n ≥ 1$.
We show by induction over $n$ that the functor $F$ preserves $n$-products for every $n ≥ 1$.
The case $n = 1$ is trivial, and the case $n = 2$ is true by assumption.

For the general case let $P$, $p_i$, $Q$, $q_j$ and $π$ be as in (2).
We know by induction that the object $F(Q)$ together with the morphisms $F(q_j) \colon F(Q) \to F(A_j)$ is a product of $F(A_1), \dotsc, F(A_{n - 1})$.
We also know by induction that the object $F(P)$ together with the two morphisms $F(π) \colon F(P) \to F(Q)$ and $F(p_n) \colon F(P) \to F(A_n)$ is a product of the two objects $F(Q)$ and $F(A_n)$.

It follows from (1) that the object $F(P)$ together with the morphisms $F(q_j) ∘ F(π) \colon F(P) \to F(A_j)$ for $j = 1, \dotsc, n - 1$ and the morphism $F(p_n) \colon F(P) \to F(A_n)$ is a product of $F(A_1), \dotsc, F(A_n)$.
But $F(q_j) ∘ F(π) = F(q_j ∘ π) = F(p_j)$ for every $j = 1, \dotsc, n - 1$.
We have thus shown that the object $F(P)$ together with the morphisms $F(p_i) \colon F(P) \to F(A_i)$ is a product of $F(A_1), \dotsc, F(A_n)$.

Comment: This shows that $F(P)$ is a product, but I additionally need that $\langle Fp_1, \dots, Fp_n \rangle$ is an isomorphism

Comment: This is the same thing: an object $P$ together with morphisms $p_i \colon P \to A_i$ is a product of $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ if and only if the morphism $⟨p_1, \dotsc, p_n⟩ \colon P \to ∏_{i = 1}^n A_i$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: ohhh that makes a lot of sense, also explains why preserve products this definition, which seemed weird to me at first. That was the piece I was missing, ty!